# Cucumber/Capybara- how to mark a test case pass or fail based on a boolean variable

Tags: cucumber, range, capybara

In a cucumber test case, I have a set of acceptable expected values in an array say acceptable. And the actual result obtained is in actualResult variable. I want the test case to pass if any of acceptable values is within a range say actualResult-2 to actualResult+2.

In short, I want to get true for the below execution because acceptable has 6 which is in the range of 2 to 7

```
irb(main):087:0> acceptable= [1,6,9]
=> [1, 6, 9]
irb(main):088:0> result = 2..7
=> 2..7
irb(main):089:0> acceptable.include?(result)
=> false
```

I thought of an indirect solution where I will do following-

```
acceptable.each do |value|
begin
  if (value.should be_within(delta).of(result))
    matches? = true
  end
rescue
  matches? = false
end
```

But here I would like to know how I can tell cucumber that if `matches? == true` pass this test case without executing the loop further.

Comment: A couple of notes: a) the indirect solution snippet is missing an `end`; and b) it looks like you are doing assignment rather than comparison on `matches? = true` (i.e. `=` instead of `==`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to terminate a loop or block.  Here's the link to [rdoc](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-break).